# Как порграммно кликнуть по svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, javascript-events

У обычных dom-элементов есть метод `click`, при вызове которого срабатывают все обработчики кликов. Но у `svg` этого метода почему-то нет. Как его кликнуть так, чтобы событие прошло все стадии?

Так, в следующем примере клик по спану срабатывает, а по svg - нет:

```js
~function () {
  var span = document.querySelector("span")
  var svg = document.querySelector("svg")

  span.click()
  svg.click()
}()
```

```css
span, svg {
  background: silver;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="console.log(event.target.tagName + ' is clicked in div')">
  <span onclick="console.log('span is clicked')"></span>
  <svg onclick="console.log('svg is clicked')"></svg>
<div>
```

Comment: `var evt = new Event('click', {'bubbles':true, 'cancelable':false});` [Вроде бы работает](https://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/syta8L2x/)

Comment: P.S. Может быть даже лучше подойдёт `MouseEvent`, чем  `Event`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85812/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-deonis).